# Has SegWit been activated yet?

Tags: segregated-witness

Is SegWit activated and when exactly did that happen? I keep getting conflicting information, any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Segwit has been locked in, but not activated yet. Approximate activation date is August 24th, 2017 around 00:36 UTC.

Edit: according to https://xbt.eu "Activation expected at ≈Tue, 22 Aug 2017 21:49:21 GMT"

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a bunch do you have a link with some information about it?

Comment: I just now looked up the specific activation date at http://segwit.party another popular site to track segwit is https://xbt.eu